# Rails - Heroku to AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services

I'm currently using Heroku for my rails app. But I plan to move to AWS for scalability reasons. Can anyone please guide on how easy it is to move to AWS from Heroku?

I see few articles:
http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Ruby/8621639827664165
https://github.com/wr0ngway/rubber/wiki

But not sure which would be the best way to proceed, specially when I would have already written a lot of migrations till I decide to move to aws.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: <p>please follow this link and deploy form screch </p> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802259/why-do-people-use-heroku-when-aws-is-present-whats-distinguishing-about-heroku"> How to deploy my rails application on AWS server.</a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no answer to your question. it all depends on the architecture of your application and the plugins that you are using.

on aws you have to take care of all the components like databases, caches etc yourself, while heroku sets them up for you.

if you are just talking about the database migration then i can point you to a blog post i wrote about migrating an application from within heroku: http://blog.nofail.de/2011/06/migrating-an-existing-app-to-heroku-celadon-cedar-stack/

Answer (score 1):

to deploy your app from Heroku to AWS there is no simple path - especially if you have to migrate a database. But one solution that really shines is [Qovery](https://www.qovery.com). It is a Heroku-like platform running on your AWS account.

They also have a tutorial on [how to deploy a RAILS app on AWS](https://hub.qovery.com/guides/tutorial/deploy-rails-with-postgresql/)